# QGenericMatrix how to return specific value from row/column

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgenericmatrix

I wanted to do matrix multiplication in QT and am able to initialize QGenericMatrix and multiply two matrixs too but how do i extract values from final matrix (specific row/column) for further calculations.

```
float values [] = {
1, 0.23, 0, -0.98,
0, 0.75, 0, -0.67,
0, 0.34, 1, 0.12,
0, 0.98, 0, 0.23
};

float values1 [] = {
34
23
12
11
};

QGenericMatrix<4,4, float> a(values);
QGenericMatrix<1,4, float> b(values1);

QGenericMatrix<1,4, float> result = a * b;
qDebug() << result;
```

From the result matrix <1,4> i want to extract each value to a different variable. I couldn't find any information in docs.

Appreciate if some one please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the operator [`()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericmatrix.html#operator-28-29):

```
float values [] = {
1, 0.23, 0, -0.98,
0, 0.75, 0, -0.67,
0, 0.34, 1, 0.12,
0, 0.98, 0, 0.23
};

float values1 [] = {34, 23, 12, 11};

QGenericMatrix<4,4, float> a(values);
QGenericMatrix<1,4, float> b(values1);

QGenericMatrix<1,4, float> result = a * b;

qDebug()<< result;

qDebug() << result(0, 0);
qDebug() << result(1, 0);
qDebug() << result(2, 0);
qDebug() << result(3, 0);
```

Output:

```
QGenericMatrix<1, 4, float>(
     28.51         
      9.88         
     21.14         
     25.07         
)
28.51
9.88
21.14
25.07
```

Comment: Thank you .so much ..  i was trying to use qDebug() << result[0][0].

Comment: @user3412649 
Unfortunately the operator `[]` is not implemented in QGenericMatrix, :)

Answer (score 0):

`QGenericMatrix` provides [operator()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericmatrix.html#operator-28-29) for that